# Removing epsilon productions from a CFG. Which is correct?

Tags: automata

I am learning how to remove epsilon productions and the result I am getting seems to vary from other results I find.

Beginning productions:

$$S \rightarrow bSb|Ba$$

$$B \rightarrow BdSc|S|\epsilon$$

The answer I came up with is:

> S -> bSb|Ba|a   B -> BdSc|dSc|S

However, I am also seeing these two differing solutions:

> S -> bSb|Ba|a   B -> BdSc|S

> S -> bSb|Ba|a|bb   B -> BdSc|dSc|S|dc|Bdc

**Which is correct?**

Comment: You can verify this yourself. The new B should be the old B except the epsilon rule. The right hand sides of the rules should be duplicated: for every B in them, you have one right hand side with B and one with epsilon. E.g. aBbBc becomes aBbBc | abBc | aBbc | abc. Do this consistently and your new B will generate the same language as the old one except the empty string, and the other nonterminals will generate the same language they used to generate. You can prove this by induction. This process suffices unless it generates a new epsilon rule for B, which doesn't happen in this case.